# Bug: Fresh install error, looking for fluid field type in user/addons but is a core addon? EEv 7.2.2

Tags: error, addons, core, fluid-field

This is a fresh install, just downloaded a copy of EEv 7.2.2 (latest) and I get this error in the admin when trying to create channels or entries:

> Error: Unable to load requested field type file: ft.fluid.field.php.
> Confirm the field type is located in the system/user/addons directory

I've double checked the downloaded system/user/addons folder and there is nothing in this directory. I tried to copy the ft.fluid.field.php from system/ee/ExpressionEngine/Addons/fluid_field to system/user/addons, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting... you shouldn't be seeing this... My gut is to grab a fresh zip off of ExpressionEngine.com and then replace your /system/ee/ExpressoinEngine/ folder from the download....

Comment: Thanks this was a big help, this is resolved now.